# How to conditionally array.map based on an input’s value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, conditional-statements, jsx

I have three inputs for a modal screen: two dropdowns and a text input field. When the second dropdown is “is empty”, the text input field should disappear, leaving two inputs on the modal.

Here’s the code without any conditional formatting:

```
render () {
   const { filterInputs = [] } = this.props;

   filterInputs.forEach((filterInput, i) => {
      this[`filter`] = React.createRef();
   });
   const filteredLevels = filterInputs.map((filterInput, i) => (
     <div className = “align-items-center” key = {i}>
       <InputElement {…filterInput.field} onChange = {this.onFilterChange} />
       <InputElement {…filterInput.operator} onChange = {this.onFilterChange} />
       <InputElement {…filterInput.operand} onChange = {this.onFilterChange} refInst={this[`filter`]} />
   ));

return (
   <Fragment>
      <{filteredLevels}
   </Fragment>
```

filterInput.operand is the field that needs to disappear based on if filterInput.operator’s value is “is Empty”. I’ve tried to add a useState hook for filterInput.operand to be disabled when filterInput.operator.value === ‘is Empty’, but it doesn’t disable anything and for some reason, it makes filterInput.field break and I can’t choose any of its dropdown options.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [disableOperand, setDisableOperand] = useState(false);

render () {
   const { filterInputs = [] } = this.props;

   filterInputs.forEach((filterInput, i) => {
      this[`filter`] = React.createRef();
   });
   const filteredLevels = filterInputs.map((filterInput, i) => (
     <div className = “align-items-center” key = {i}>
       <InputElement {…filterInput.field} onChange = {this.onFilterChange} />
       <InputElement {…filterInput.operator} onChange = {(event) => { if (event.target.value === 'is Empty') { setDisableOperand(true) } else { setDisableOperand(false) } }} />
       <InputElement {…filterInput.operand} disabled={disableOperand} onChange = {this.onFilterChange} refInst={this[`filter`]} />
   ));

return (
   <Fragment>
      <{filteredLevels}
   </Fragment>
```

Here, I’ve added a useState hook for the disabled value of filterInput.operand. I also added an onChange event to filterInput.operator, so that when its value is “is Empty”, it sets disableOperand to true, which will then disable filterInput.operand.

Comment: I tried this but I need the operator to also have {this.onFilterChange} and it disables use of the first InputElement for some reason.